# two asymptotic comparison on sparse graph and misunderstanding point

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, asymptotics, computer-science

I read in my notes:

if we use Dijkstra $|V|$ times ($|V|$ number of vertexes) for finding **all pairs shortest paths** in graph $G$, We get time complexity for Dijkstra algorithm as $O(VE+ V^2 log V)$ and if we run bellman ford algorithm $|V|$ times we get time $O(V^2E)$.

The above details is not important.

I read too, in sparse graph Dijkstra works better (i.e: $O(VE+ V^2 log V)$ is better asymptotic respect to $O(V^2E)$ in sparse graph).

I think sparse graph is $ |E| \in O(V)$  or $E=o(V^2/\log V)$. Infact I have two misunderestanding:

$1)$ which one is used to show a graph is sparse commonly?

$2)$ according to $(1)$ how we can intuitively understand $O(VE+ V^2 log V)$ is better asymptotic respect to $O(V^2E)$ at least I think the reverse is true.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133376/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3950318/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well said by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) *The distinction between sparse and dense graphs is rather vague, and depends on the context.*

The accepted answer in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599143/what-is-the-distinction-between-sparse-and-dense-graphs#:%7E:text=Sparse%20graph%20is%20a%20graph,can%20be%20a%20disconnected%20graph.), also state

> Dense graph is a graph in which the number of edges is close to the maximal number of edges. Sparse graph is a graph in which the number of edges is close to the minimal number of edges.

Sparse or Dense is not really a proper property of a graph. it will indeed depend on the context. Your two "definitions" are perfectly both acceptable.

For the second point, if you suppose that $E=O(V)$, then

- Dijkstra works in $O(VE+V^2\log V)=O(V^2+V^2\log V)=o(V^3)$
- bellman ford works in $O(V^2E)=O(V^3)$

if you suppose that $E=o(V^2/\log V)$, then

- Dijkstra works in $O(VE+V^2\log V)=o(V^3/\log V)$
- bellman ford works in $O(V^2E)=o(V^4/\log V)$

So that Dijkstra is more efficient in both cases.